# How to create a 301 error?

Tags: http-status-code-301

I would like to create a 301 error situation in my web site. I can write the htaccess code to redirect when 301 error happen. But I don know how to check the code. Please help me.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. If you're setting up a 301 redirect, try accessing the page and if it redirects you to the new page, then it works.

Comment: I know the htacess code .Redirect 301  http://jobslanda.com/301.php.  But How can I chek tje working of the site ?

Comment: you need to accept the answer of your previous questions to motivate others to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The 301 status code means "permanent redirection." If you have a page at oldpage.html and have moved it to newpage.html, you have the oldpage.html redirect to newpage.html with a 301 code. This tells search engines and whatnot that the page has moved. So you really shouldn't be doing a catchall for redirecting these pages. This isn't like a 404 where everything can go to one page where you show a message. If a page has moved, you should be pointing to the new page.

In PHP you can use `header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');` to set the 301 header. I think this should get picked up by your htaccess and redirect the page.

Comment: My thinking is if you have a page with that header, it will be caught by the htaccess file and be redirected to whatever you have set. I've updated my answer with some info on 301 and why I don't think you should do what you're doing.